# Binding Angular 2 components with a list of selectors string format

Tags: javascript, angular, binding

I define a list widget component selectors in Angular 2. It's still OK when I type `<app-xxx-widget></app-xxx-widget>` in HTML file. The problem is that I have an array of those component selectors with string format and when I bind `{{ widgetTag }}`(use `*ngFor="let widgetTag of widgetTagList"`), the browser just understand widgetTag as a text, not Angular Component. How can I solve this problem?
I think it's impossible in this case

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: <div class="col-xs-{{ gridConfig.grid_column - gridConfig.grid_column_coe }}" *ngFor="let widgetTag of widgetTagList">
            {{ widgetTag }}
        </div>

Comment: Is it easy for you to understand? If not, I will explain more..

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create them, it's a bit tricky but totally doable.

Some examples:

http://blog.rangle.io/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-2/

https://medium.com/@tudorgergely/injecting-components-dynamically-in-angular-2-3d36594d49a0

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Basic example to load 1 component:

- inject `Injector` and `NgModuleFactoryLoader`
- add one container element in your template (such as `<div #componentReference></div>`)
- add one component reference element to hold reference to created component
- create a component from it's factory

  ```
  public component: any;
  @ViewChild('componentReference') componentReference: any;

  public createComponent(module: string, component: string) {

  this.loader.load(module).then(

    (f: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {

      const moduleRef = f.create(this.injector);   

      (<any>moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver)._factories.forEach(
        (cF) => {
          if (cF.componentType.name === component) {

            const fac = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(cF.componentType);
            this.componentReference = this.component.createComponent(fac);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  ```

  }

This example is made with component `.name` but can easily be changed to use selector however you will have to figure that out yourself.
Make sure that desired component is located in your modules `entryComponents`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support, I have found a solution when watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjCOe1PcP5g